# Adding tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, unix, bioinformatics

I've been trying to add this table but all data is embedded in one column in the SQL matrix.
For example:

```
mysql> describe genomas;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Object | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| GOID   | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

the data I want to upload is in a .txt file. 
then I upload buuut..

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'GOhumanbegin.txt' INTO TABLE genomas FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
Query OK, 499486 rows affected, 65535 warnings (20.20 sec)
Records: 499486  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 499486
```

(<-IT IS SHOWING WARNINGS...but why?)

```
mysql> SELECT Object, GOID  FROM genomas LIMIT 10;
```

What i got:

```
| Object                | GOID |
+-----------------------+------+
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0003723 |      |
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0005829 |      |
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0008486 |      |
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0046872 |      |
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0052840 |      |
| A0A024RBG1 GO:0052842 |      |
| A0A075B6H7 GO:0002250 |      |
| A0A075B6H7 GO:0005886 |      |
| A0A075B6H7 GO:0019814 |      |
| A0A075B6H8 GO:0002250 |      |
```

What I expected:

```
| Object                | GOID           |
+-----------------------+----------------+
| A0A024RBG1            | GO:0003723     |
| A0A024RBG1            | GO:0005829     |
| A0A024RBG1            |  GO:0008486    |
| A0A024RBG1            |  GO:0046872    |
| A0A024RBG1            |  GO:0052840    |
| A0A024RBG1            |  GO:0052842    |
| A0A075B6H7            |  GO:0002250    |
| A0A075B6H7            |  GO:0005886    |
| A0A075B6H7            |  GO:0019814    |
| A0A075B6H8            |  GO:0002250    |
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1MbT.png)

Comment: How do you know your data is terminated by `\t`. Are there any data mapping, to the proper way to read the file? I'm not sure if it is terminated by tabs, but just binary data separated by whitespaces.

Comment: I think we need to see a fair representation of the csv

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your CSV file is in format

```
object,goid
A0A024RBG1,GO:0003723
A0A024RBG1,GO:0005829
A0A024RBG1,GO:0008486
A0A024RBG1,GO:0046872 


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'sample.csv' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

if you can give more specific details about your *file* I can provide a more detailed answer.